# How to run GUI applications as another user on Linux, without SSH and kde/gksudo?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

Now that kdesudo and gksudo are disappearing from distributions, what is a reasonable way to run a GUI application as a different user?

My use case is that I do not want the application to be able to directly access my actual home directory. There are probably ways to escalate privileges to my user via the X11 server, but that’s not my concern. My concern is that some applications will write data to my home directory which I want to be able to get rid of easily. I want to be able, when I’m done with using the application, to rm -rf the home directory of that other user and reclaim all disk space.

I would normally resort to `ssh -X`, however, due to the nature of the application, this causes noticeable delays and annoyances in using it. `kdesudo` is working fine while I still have it installed, but a fresh installation of the OS would make it disappear.

PolKit is being proposed as a solution to replace kdesudo, but as far as I understand it, PolKit only replaces running things as root, not running things as a different user.

So what other options are there? Is there a set of magic options I can pass to `sudo` which’ll work reliably?

Comment: Consider **also** Mandatory Access Control, such as `apparmor`. Another trick I do, is to have a directory `~/+Files`. I put everything in here, and symlink my dot files. It is a little bit of upfront work, but then I can easily find junk that has been put into `~`. I need to audit and decide what to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I have this is an executable file named `xsudo`. it may be buggy: It is not well tested. But often used.

```
#/bin/bash

inner() {
    su  - "$user" -c "xauth list" |
        grep "$(echo "$display" |
                cut -d ':' -f 2 |
                cut -d '.' -f 1 |
                sed -e s/^/:/ ) " |
        xargs -n 3 xauth add &&
        "$@"
}

if [ "$1" = "---innermode" ]
then
    shift
    user="$1"
    display="$2"
    shift 2
    inner "$@"
else
    self="$0"
    sudo "${self}" ---innermode "$USER" "$DISPLAY" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you explain how this works and how to use it? When I call it with ``./xsudo gedit``, it seems to just hang.

Comment: It is working for me (but may be buggy). Are the environment variables USER and DISPLAY, set correctly?

Comment: That depends on what "correctly" means in this context. ``USER`` is set to my username, and ``DISPLAY`` is ``:0``. I’m not running Wayland.

Comment: Nevermind. I used your script as an inspiration to build my own: https://github.com/horazont/xsudo

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [answer by ctrl-alt-delor](https://superuser.com/a/1527506/122572), I rolled [my own script, available on my github](https://github.com/horazont/xsudo).

To use the X11 server of a different user, a proper X authority file is needed. This file contains credentials to use the X11 server and it is typically set up by the graphical login process.

The data needed to re-create such a file can be obtained using `xauth nextract /dev/stdout "$DISPLAY"` as the original user. The output of that command is text data which can be fed into `xauth nmerge /dev/stdin` on the *target* user to provide it with the data needed to access the original users X11 server (plus the `DISPLAY` variable).

In order to avoid messing with a possibly running X11 server of that other user (multi-seated systems) and in order to avoid interfering with other Xauth forwarding methods, it is better to write the authority data into a file only accessible by the *target* user and export the path to that file as `XAUTHORITY` variable.

The linked script does all of this, and it goes out of its way to clean up the environment of the target user’s command (to avoid things like `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to pass through), as well as avoiding that the output of `xauth nextract` ends up in `ps`, accessible to other users (even temporarily).

Answer (score 0):

I would expect e.g.

`$ su - sister   # login as 'sister'..., assuming the user exists`
... this to cause any GUI applications to obey the usual user restrictions and limits - as always - **when launched from that shell**.

```
$ man su
...
NAME
       su - change user ID or become superuser

SYNOPSIS
       su [options] [username]

...
```

Comment: That doesn’t work with GUI applications. If you think it does, please show me how.

Comment: @Jonas: It does on some distributions which use pam_xauth as part of the default configuration. _(Or if the user previously granted access using `xhost +SI:localuser:<targetname>`, or if the user has previously disabled X11 access control via `xhost +LOCAL:` or even via `xhost +`.)_

Comment: I also use `xhost +local:` and `su - otheruser` and can execute X (GUI) apps. On Debian 10. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions provided here don't integrate with Wayland and PulseAudio.

I wrote `ego` (Alter Ego), which automatically handles `xhost` and Wayland and PulseAudio socket sharing with another local user: https://github.com/intgr/ego

However, it currently doesn't revoke privileges after the program quits.

If you run into problems, please open an issue on GitHub. I may be the only user of it, so it hasn't gotten much testing yet, any feedback would be welcome.